# localhost load xml file with js

Tags: javascript, html, xml, apache

ok i have my files on apache so i can read it localhost i have one issue cause iam new and i really cant understand how to load xml files with js i see all the topics in stuck overflow and iam stuck .....

i have the main htm file .  should i change the path to var indexFile and var xmlFile to my localhost like this var indexFile=`"file:///C:/Apache24/htdocs/data/index.xml";` ??

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var direction=1;
    var titleis="Loading.........";
    function showLoading(){
        //if (window.status.charAt(0)=="O"){direction=0}
        //if (window.status.charAt(titleis.length-1)=="O"){direction=1}
        if (direction==0){
            window.status=window.status.charAt(titleis.length-1)+window.status.substr(0,titleis.length-1);
        }else{
            window.status=window.status.substr(1,titleis.length-1)+window.status.charAt(0);
        }
    }
    window.status=titleis;
    var timeID=setInterval("showLoading();", 100);
</script>



<script Src="scripts/config.js" language=jscript></script>
<script Src="scripts/general.js" language=jscript></script>
<script Src="inc/header.js" language=jscript></script>
<script src="scripts/grid.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/xml.js"></script>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  // this page should never load inside of another frame
    window.onerror = handleError;

    var xmlHttp = new Active.XML.Table;
    var xmlLoaded=false;
    var xmlData;
    var indexFile="data/Index.xml";
    var xmlIndex =CreateXMLObj(false);
    var hasOrders=false;
    var idxLoaded=false;
    var HtmlIdx;
    var xmlFile="data/Catalogue.xml";

    var RootTag = "CATALOGUE";
    var RecordTag = "PART";
  function InitSync()
  {
      if( "object" == typeof( top.deeptree ) && "unknown" == typeof( top.deeptree.Sync ) )
      {
        top.deeptree.Sync();
      }
  }
  function SetTitle(name){
    _Title = name
    document.title =_Title;
  }
  function SetAsterisc(){
    document.title =_Title + '*';
  }
    function loaddata(){

        if (!xmlLoaded) {
            if (!xmlHttp.isReady()){
                window.status="Φόρτωση δεδομένων...";
                xmlHttp.defineProperty("async",false);
                xmlHttp.setURL(xmlFile);//  provide data URL
                xmlHttp.request();//    start asyncronous data retrieval    
                window.status="Done";
            }
            xmlData=xmlHttp.getXML();
            if (xmlHttp.isReady() && !xmlHttp.getAsync()){
                xmlLoaded=true;
            }else{
                xmlLoaded=true;
            }
        }
        return xmlLoaded;
    }
    function loadIndexes(){
        if (!idxLoaded) {
            window.status="Φόρτωση δεδομένων...";
            if(xmlIndex.load(indexFile)){
                idxLoaded=true;
            }else{
                idxLoaded=false;
                alert(  'parseError : ' + xmlIndex.parseError.reason + '\n' +
                        'Code       : ' + xmlIndex.parseError.errorCode + '\n' +
                        'Line       : ' + xmlIndex.parseError.line + '\n' +
                        'Source     : ' + xmlIndex.parseError.srcText + '\n' +
                        'Pos        : ' + xmlIndex.parseError.linepos + '\n' +
                        'filepos    : ' + xmlIndex.parseError.filepos + '\n'
                        ,1,document.title);
            }
            window.status="Done";
        }
        return idxLoaded;
    }
    function strnull(value,_default){
        if (value==null || value==""){
            return _default;
        }
        return value;
    }



    function getNameID(AID){
        if(AID<0){return}
        return new String(getsafeData(xmlData,"//" + RecordTag + "[AID=" + AID + "]/NameID"));
    }
    function getPictureNo(AID){
        if(AID<0){return}
        return new String(getsafeData(xmlData,"//" + RecordTag + "[AID=" + AID + "]/PictureNo"));
    }
    function getOrder(AID){
        if(AID<0){return}
        return parseInt(getsafeData(xmlData,"//" + RecordTag + "[AID=" + AID + "]/Order"));
    }
    function getPicName(PicNo){
        return getsafeData(xmlIndex,"//menuItem" +  "[@id=" + PicNo + "]/@name");
    }

    function SetOrder(AID,value){
        if(AID<0){return false;}
        xmlData.selectSingleNode("//" + RecordTag+ "[AID=" + AID + "]/Order").text=value;
        hasOrders=true;
        return true;
    }
    function ClearOrder(AID){
        if(AID<0){return false;}
        return SetOrder(AID,"");
    }
    function ClearOrders(){
        var StrQuery = "//" + RecordTag + "[Order>0]";
        var xmlNodeLst = xmlData.selectNodes(StrQuery);
        for(var i=0;i<xmlNodeLst.length;i++){
            xmlNodeLst(i).selectSingleNode("Order").text="";
            var id=xmlNodeLst(i).selectSingleNode("AID").text;
            SetOrder(id,"");
        }
        hasOrders=false;
        return true;
    }
    function InputOrder(AID){
        if(AID>=0){
            var oldvalue=getOrder(AID);
            if(isNaN(oldvalue)){oldvalue=0};
            var value=window.prompt("Εισάγετε ποσότητα για το αντ/κό με Αρ.Ονομαστικου :'" + getNameID(AID) +"'.",oldvalue);
            if (value!=null){
                if(isNaN(value)){value=0};
                if (value!=oldvalue){
                    if (value > 0) {
                        SetOrder(AID,value);
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS LANGUAGE=javascript>
function window_onbeforeunload() {
    if (hasOrders){
        window.event.returnValue="\n---------------------------------------------------------------------\nΑν φύγετε από τη σελίδα θα χαθούν οι καταχωρήσεις σας.\n---------------------------------------------------------------------\nΠΑΤΗΣΤΕ OK για να φύγετε.\nΠΑΤΗΣΤΕ CANCEL για να παραμείνετε.\n\n";
    }
}
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript FOR=document EVENT=onreadystatechange>
    document_onreadystatechange();
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS LANGUAGE=javascript>
function document_onreadystatechange(){
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        clearInterval(timeID);
        //window.showModelessDialog("logo1st.htm",self,'dialogwidth: 558px; DialogHeight:430px;status: no; resizable:no;help:no;maximize:no;minimize:no;');
        window.status="Done";

    }
}
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript FOR=window EVENT=onbeforeunload>
 window_onbeforeunload();
</SCRIPT>

<!---->
<script language=javascript>
var urlIs=QueryString('url')
if (urlIs==null || urlIs==''){urlIs='logo1st.htm';}

document.write('<FRAMESET name="FrmSet" onload="" rows="36,*" border="1" FRAMESPACING="0" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">');
    document.write('<FRAME name="fraTop" src="top.htm" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize  TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0"></FRAME>');
    document.write('<FRAMESET name="fstMain" cols="1,*" border="1" frameborder="1" FRAMESPACING="2"     TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">');
      document.write('<FRAME name="fraLeftFrame" src="Left.htm?frame=true&selection=' + QueryString('selection') + '"scrolling="no" noresize TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" FRAMEBORDER="1" BORDER="1"></FRAME>');
      document.write('<FRAME name="fraRightFrame" src="' + urlIs + '?frame=true&hidetoc=false&selection=' + QueryString('selection') + '" FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDER="0" BORDERCOLOR="#b1c3c0"></FRAME>');
    document.write('</FRAMESET>');
document.write('</FRAMESET>');
   </script>

</HTML>
```

this code works on IE 5 I THINK BUT not ON latest browsers  what i have to change for make it work my xml docs  are in apache `C:\Apache24\htdocs\data`

Comment: Is it essential that it runs on IE5?

Comment: yeah this code works on I6 and previous editions .. he was able to load the xml but not anymore on new IE and not at all for other browsers ]

Comment: Try like this "http://localhost/data/index.xml"

Comment: i change the paths but nothing its not display the xml table with records on my page i think something is wrong with my load xml method that cause that error

Comment: he open the xml file when i click the link but not work on my js code